# Java GUI wont show

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a program with the raspberry pi that goes full screen and when I run this program in eclipse "on the pi" it works fine and looks something like this

[image]

But when I export the file to a runnable jar, this happens

[image]

But I get no errors and it doesn't close it just shows the windows but nothing happens.

Here is the code for the frame that you see,

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tester extends JFrame {

// R3T Object
r3t R3T = new r3t();

// Random Stuff
public static boolean updateMe = false;
private int count = 0;
public static int R3TCount = 0;

private ImageIcon tank_full = new ImageIcon("src/res/level.png");
private ImageIcon tank_empty = new ImageIcon("src/res/tank_empty.png");

// For drawing the rectangle Y = NON DEFAULT
public static int NDRECT_Y = -0;
public static int TankValue = -0;
public static String TankLevel = "0.0";

//RATIOS
private int X1 = (int)(WIDTH * 0.06);
private int Y1 = (int)(HEIGHT * 0.111);
private int Y2 = (int)(HEIGHT * 0.781);

//Screen
public static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
public static  int WIDTH = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
public static int HEIGHT = (int)screenSize.getHeight();


public Tester() {
    //Screen Size
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("Tank Level");
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setLocation(0, 0);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawImage(tank_empty.getImage(), 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, this);

    // REMINDER : x , y, x, y
    g.drawImage(tank_full.getImage(), X1, Y1, TankValue, Y2, this);

    drawTankLevel(g);
    g.dispose();
    doTask();
    count += 1;
}

public void drawTankLevel(Graphics temp) {
    temp.setFont(new Font("Vendana", 0, 30));
    temp.drawString("        ", (WIDTH / 2) - 20, (HEIGHT / 2));
    temp.drawString(TankLevel, (WIDTH / 2)- 20, (HEIGHT / 2));
    temp.dispose();
}

public static void updateTankLevel(double level) {
    TankValue = (int) ((WIDTH * level / 100) - (WIDTH * 0.12));
    TankLevel = String.valueOf(level);
}

public static double getTankLevel() {
    return Double.parseDouble(TankLevel);
}

public void doTask() {
    if (count == 0) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println ("CNT: "+R3TCount);
                        System.out.println ("-----------------");

                        R3T.GetDeviceInfo();
                        R3TCount += 1;
                        repaint();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (InterruptedException t) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        repaint();
    }

    if (updateMe) {
        System.out.println("R3T: Updated Guage!");
        updateMe = false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester test = new Tester();
}
}
```

This is the code that changes the value, Its a Bluetooth scan and it gets the name of the device, I know this works fine though because it prints the value it just doesn't update it on screen

```
public void calculateTankLevel(String tempDevice) {
    String deviceName = tempDevice.substring(18, tempDevice.length());

    int byt_div = 0xE005;
    int num_div = 10;
    byte[] valueRay;

    valueRay = hexStringToByteArray(deviceName.substring(deviceName.length() - 4, deviceName.length()));

    double value = twoBytesToShort(valueRay[0], valueRay[1]);
    double val = ((value - byt_div) / num_div);

    System.out.println ("R3T: Calculated Tank Level");

    if (val == Tester.getTankLevel()) {
        //The value hasnt change dont update.
        System.out.println ("R3T: Tank Level *NU*");
    } else {
        //Value has changed update UI and send to webservice
        //R3TWebCall.sendTankLevel(val);
        System.out.println("Tank Level: "+val);
        Tester.updateTankLevel(val);
        Tester.updateMe = true;
    }
}
```

I added another part to my code this is it.

```
File f = new File("res/level.png");
    if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
        System.out.println("TANK FULL EXISTS");
    } else {
        System.out.println("TANK FULL DOES NOT EXISTS");
    }

    File f1 = new File("res/tank_empty.png");
    if(f1.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
        System.out.println("TANK EMPTY EXIST");
    } else {
        System.out.println("TANK FULL DOES NOT EXISTS");
    }
```

After adding this it will tell me if the time exists where I am looking for it and when I run it in eclipse it says the files does exist but! When I export to a jar file it says it does not exist!

Comment: I am not about to click on those links. Care to actually post the images instead?

Comment: Yeah! Im sorry one sec! @rabbitguy

Comment: Show us the important parts of the code.

Comment: I added the code for the frame! @hexafraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a long time ago, you probably didn't declare your ressource folder as "class folder". Right click your project, then go to properties, then java build path, and click on "add class folder". A window will pop up, select your ressource folder "res" by checking the checkbox. Your may need to also modify your path.

Also move your res folder outside src folder, src folder is only for the sources of the code not for ressources.
To load a ressource you could also use MyClass.class.getRessourceAsStream("path");

Comment: Hmm, I tried moving the res folder outside of src and it didn't seem to work, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative paths to your images files, may be that help. Please post also code for your JLabel or whatever presents number in the middle of frame.
I am not sure but you may missing repaint method in your update level tank method. You change value of string more effectively by using `setText(String s)` for your `JLabel`.
Relative path is something that doesn't depends on directories on your local machine but would be machine independent.
This is short article to better understand a topic of relative vs absolute:
http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: Also what do you mean when you say relative path?

Comment: see edit, by relative I mean sometimes it's not really safe to depend on writing src/dir1/dir2 but I'd rather go in "../src/dir1/dir2" scheme where your going back from current directory and then follow to the right one.

Comment: How would I do something like this though since my images are in the jar file? take them out of the src/res and put them with the java files? @kolboc

Comment: Not really, ceep your project like you do but be sure your paths are relative. Example: 
I had images in src/images/(Here my images)
So my path to them in code has to be: "./src/images/heart.png"
As from file compilation place it  has to go one folder backwards (. does the job) and then follows path: /src/images/heart.png

Comment: Yeah that's how my project is setup and that's where my images are!